# C++/CX WMI PropertyData array type

Tags: wmi, c++-cx, system.management

I need to read the values of `System.Management.PropertyData` when it's an array.

*PropertyData.IsArray Property*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.propertydata.isarray?view=netframework-4.7.2

I have no idea how to convert `PropertyData.Value` to something readable.
If I print `PropertyData.Value` as it is, I get a *"System.String[]"*

If I convert it to `array<String>`

```
for each(String s in (array<String>^)(object->Properties[propertyName]->Value))
    Console::WriteLine(s);
```

I get a

> Error (active) the element type of a cli::array must be a handle or value type

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's by no means valid c++ code.

Comment: It's Microsoft C++/CX  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/quick-reference-c-cx?view=vs-2017

Comment: Tag your question appropriately then, but don't use the standard c++ tag please.

Comment: for each (String^ s in array<String^>^)...

Comment: @kennyzx Thanks, worked. You better post it as an answer so I can accept it, commit this ticket I'm working on and go back working on a logic, elegant and standard C++

Comment: The syntax is somewhat unusual. I only find C++/CLI useful once in my life when I need to reuse a large block of old C code in a library and the library is to be used in a .NET application. By using C++/CLI I can use both .NET classes and C in the same library.

Comment: I'm not a MS developer so, every time I have to code for Windows, I find MS code illogical and anti intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a syntax error.

The correct form is

```
for each (String^ s in (array<String^>^)...
```